# Chat Application issue

Tags: java, sockets, chat

I have made a chat application in JAVA Socket, in which I run Server.java file and Clients connect through applet. It works well on localhost(I use NetBeans). I have a free domain from co.cc and 000webhost.com as webhosting. Now i want to run Server.java on my co.cc domain so that Clients can connect. How should I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Run your server on your webhost.com. Since applets may connect only to server they were downloaded from you need web server on that host. It is not a problem: if it is lunux you can use apache web server (`httpd`) that is typically installed on each linux.

Now you should write your `<applet>` tag on your html page so that pass the server address to your applet. The easiest way to do this is if you are writing jsp or php but you can do this using dynamic HTML too.

I believe that's it.

The problem is that if you want "real" users to use your system you will meet problems of firewalls. Typically users are behind firewall, so that they cannot perform any TCP connection to any port. But I understood that this is what you are using. So, be ready that some of your users will fail to use your chat.

To penetrate firewall you should perform communication over HTTP. In this case your server side will be written as HTTP servlet.

Please do not hesitate to ask concrete questions if you decide to go this way. 
Anyway good luck.

Comment: i am not able to get your idea, can you please elaborate

Answer (score 0):

It depends on hosting and type of your application, if you've done it using servlets or jsp it will work in hostings with tomcat or other java app servers , anyway  you need to provide more details about you implementation. Best regards!